# AWS MSK posting to topics very slow

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-lambda, aws-msk

We have the same architecture under two different accounts on AWS. One is our development environment, and the other is our QC environment. In our QC environment, it takes (suspiciously) 60 seconds, give or take a millisecond or two, to post to a topic. We are posting from java code in a lambda.  Up to the point that the lambda posts to the topic, it runs very fast, about 40 ms to do XSD validation and transformation of an XML message to JSON. We have meticulously gone over the MSK configurations in both environments and have not found a difference. The same goes for the lambda. In our development environment, the message is posted in about 2 ms.

Our configuration is one broker in three zones. The broker is Kafka version 2.8.1. We are using the default MSK cluster configuration. The MSK cluster is in the same VPC as the lambda, and they are attached to the same subnets and the same security group. The lambda is set to 10 GB of memory with 512 MB of ephemeral storage. The lambda passes all three brokers in the producer configuration. All of this is the same in our development environment.

Looking at the cloud watch metrics for the MSK cluster in the QC environment, it is essentially idle. Highest CPU utilization is 2% and memory barely even blips above the bottom of the graph.

Google doesn't produce much in the way of helpful information. AWS documentation is hit and miss on the subject. I'm posting this here in the hope that someone has had this problem and can guide us out of the wilderness.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you had any luck in figuring this out? we observe something similar but while consuming from MSK